# Beginner, cannot import in Lean

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

I am an absolute beginner, not a programmer, trying to learn formal verification with [Logic and Proof](https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/introduction.html).
I cannot import anything in Lean.

I extract the tar file for the binary to `/tmp` then do

```
/tmp/lean-3.4.1-linux/bin/./lean /tmp/test.lean
```

It works except when I am importing anything. So if my file `test.lean` just says

```
open classical
example (P : Prop) : P ∨ ¬ P := em P
```

there is no error.
But if the same file instead says

```
import data.set
```

I get the error message

```
/tmp/test.lean:1:0: error: file 'data/set' not found in the LEAN_PATH  
/tmp/test.lean:1:0: error: invalid import: data.set  
could not resolve import: data.set
```

A similar error occurs with `import data.nat`.

What am I doing wrong, and what should I do? 
I am using Ubuntu 16.04.
Please note that since I am a beginner, I have never compiled anything from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution by contacting Prof. Avigad directly.

It turns out that the book uses not only the standard library but also the Lean mathematical components library, [mathlib](https://github.com/leanprover/mathlib).
Installing it worked for me. I can now do `import data.set` without getting an error.

Comment: how do you install mathlib?

Answer (score 0):

These packages are hidden in `init`.

```
import init.classical
import init.data.nat
import init.data.set
```

But I believe that Lean imports everything in `init` by default, so you actually would not need the lines above.

You can also skip `open` and qualify invocations.

```
example (P : Prop) : P ∨ ¬ P := classical.em P
```

Comment: I remember having tried something like that, and it didn't work. What fixed the issue was installing mathlib---see my answer.